# Can this "if" statement be simplified?

Tags: php, if-statement

I have an `if` statement that verifies when `<img>` tag is missing dimensions (`width`/`height`) or if they are blank (`width=""`/`height=""`), for example:

```
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" alt="Blank width/height" width="" height="">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" alt="Blank width" width="">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" alt="Blank height" height="">
<img src="https://placehold.it/100x50" alt="No width/height">
```

The `if` statement below works for me. However, I wanted to know if it's possible to simplify the logic that I am using below. [Here's the link to the full source code](https://github.com/factmaven/specify-image-dimensions/blob/master/specify-image-dimensions.php).

```
if (
    # There is no width
    ! in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) ||
    # There is no height
    ! in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) ||
    # The width is blank (width="")
    ( in_array( 'width', $img[1] ) && in_array( '""', $img[2] ) ) ||
    # The height is blank (height="")
    ( in_array( 'height', $img[1] ) && in_array( '""', $img[2] ) )
) {
# Code here...
}
```

Comment: Isn't it possible for `$img[2]` to contain a `""` without it corresponding to width or height? (e.g. `""` in alt?)

Comment: Should be moved to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @apokryfos Just updated my question with my attempt at it, is that the best logic though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to simplify the logic by doing the following:

```
if ( ! in_array( 'width|height', $img[1] ) || in_array( '""', $img[2] ) ) {
    # Code here...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = ['width','height'];
foreach ($search as $value) {
    if(!in_array($value, $img[1]) || (in_array($value, $img[1]) && in_array('""', $img[2])) {
        // code away
    }
}
```

Or you could always use jQuery to check your defined elements properties, or even define a width and height in css rather than using inline styling.

Comment: Updated my attempt to simplifying it in the question, what do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, export all checks in a function, in which you check each single condition and return corresponding value. As the saying goes:

> Fail early, fail fast

```
if(illegalImage($img)) {
// Code here ...
}

private function illegalImage(array $imgData) {
    // check the array since we're in a validation function, so be thorough
    if (count($imgData) < 3) { // or whatever check makes sense here
        return true;
    }
    if (!in_array('width', $imgData[1])) {
        return true;
    }
    if (!in_array('height', $imgData[1])) {
        return true;
    }
    /* you'd have failed earlier if 'width' or 'height' was missing
     * so no need of complicated boolean expressions here
     */
    if (in_array('""', $img[2])) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Isn't that making it bigger since I'm creating a whole new function for it?

Comment: It's more readable, easy to maintain and extend - big plus in my books. Think about revisiting it in months or having to add another condition.